# ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization always returns "Not Determined" and prompt is never shown

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, permissions, ads

I have read all exisiting posts about this topic, but until now I can not get it to work.
Somehow calling ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization  never shows the popup.
I added Privacy - Tracking Usage Description to the info list. I also turned on the system permissions.

I am developing the app with SwiftUI. Target device runs ios 15.4.
Any ideas what else to try? Maybe this is related to swiftUI?

**Code:**

```
DeckListView(decks: $store.decks){
             Task {
                  ....
            }
        }
      }.onAppear{
        requestPermission()
      }


   func requestPermission() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
      if #available(iOS 14, *) {

          ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { status in
          switch status {
          case .authorized:
            print("Authorized")
            print(ASIdentifierManager.shared().advertisingIdentifier)
          case .denied:
            print("Denied")
          case .notDetermined:
            // Tracking authorization dialog has not been shown
            // always the case for me
            print("Not Determined")
          case .restricted:
            print("Restricted")
          @unknown default:
            print("Unknown")
          }
        }
      }
       
    }

  }
```

Comment: When doing this `onAppear` you have to delay it a little using `DispatchQueue` `asycAfter`

Comment: @loremipsum Thanks, I already have this delay in request permission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the source of my problem.

I accidentally called `ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization` twice.
The first time I called while the app was not in an active state. It seems if the first call is made outside active state, any other calls will no longer show the popup.